# Is it possible to read the log file using Chainsaw?

Tags: logging, log4j, apache-chainsaw

I am having several log files [ generated via log4j ]. I got to know that we can use [Chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html) to read those logs [ though we can reads those logs in notepad as well ].
But i am unable to figure out how to open a stored log file to see its content. So the simple question is, `Is it possible to read the log file using Chainsaw?`

Comment: Please don't double-post (dupe now deleted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [Chainsaw v2 Log Viewer](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html) on Windows.

In the File menu there is an option 'Load Log4j file', which will allow you to open a Log4j XML log file.

Of course, the file you are trying to open must confirm to the log4j XML schema.

Comment: @coco: i saw that option, but it is expecting an XML file. whereas i am having a .log file.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, Chainsaw will only read log4j formatted XML files - so I'm afraid the answer to your question is 'no', Chainsaw cannot read your logs because they are not in the expected format

Answer (score 2):

Yes - as long as each log entry ends with the 'message' and is newline delimited, you should be able to parse the log file using LogFilePatternReceiver.

Example log line:

20100128 11:35:34.546 [main] INFO - package1.package2.SomeLoggerName - Message here line1
message here line2

These two lines, representing one log entry, can be parsed with this logFormat:

TIMESTAMP [THREAD] LEVEL - LOGGER - MESSAGE

See the LogFilePatternReceiver JavaDoc for more information (available from Chainsaw's help menu) and the example receiver configuration (available from the Welcome tab, the 'view example receiver configuration' button).

Comment: How about the log record looks like:
<log4j:event category="PROTO" timestamp="01-29-2010 17:13:54.65" priority="WARN" thread="Connect_693">
<log4j:message><![CDATA[###Connection: Error reading object:Connection reset]]></log4j:message>
<log4j:NDC><![CDATA[nodaltest,10.100.129.70,XXX]]></log4j:NDC>
</log4j:event>

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Chainsaw can read regular text log files - use a LogFilePatternReceiver.  See the example configuration available from the Welcome tab.

Comment: How about the text log has special/custom layout?

Answer (score 1):

Your log file contains 'priority' and 'category' attributes instead of 'level', 'logger', which are supported by default in Chainsaw.

Can you change your layout to generate level & category attributes?  If so, Chainsaw should be able to process your log file.

If you need to use category & priority attribute names, I'd suggest pulling down log4j's XmlDecoder source and modifying it to accept priority & category attribute names.  You can then configure Chainsaw to use a LogFileXMLReceiver and specify your own Decoder implementation.

Chainsaw's Welcome tab provides an example receiver configuration.

Here's the source for XMLDecoder:
https://github.com/apache/logging-chainsaw/blob/chainsaw-2.0.0-rc1/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/xml/XMLDecoder.java

The JavaDoc for LogFileXMLReceiver should be available from Chainsaw's help menu.